# this.setState is not a function. React Native noobie

Tags: react-native, setstate

I keep getting the following error: this.setState is undefined with my React Native project. I have never seen this error before in React, but React Native is new to me. I have done some research and there are many people suggesting to either use a constructor and bind(this) or use an arrow function in the onPress property. I have tried both, but neither seem to work. Please also note that my first 2 functions work fine it is the createUser function that is throwing the error. I would appreicate any help, thanks in advance. Here is my original code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../firebase.js';



class Auth extends Component {

  state = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    error: ""}

onChangeUsername= (event) => {
this.setState({ username: event.nativeEvent.text})
}

onChangePassword= (event) => {  

this.setState({ password: event.nativeEvent.text})
}

 createUser = (event) =>{

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {

                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;

                if(errorCode === "auth/invalid-email")
                {this.setState({error: 2})}

                console.log(error.code);
                console.log(error.message);
                          });
                        }

render(){




return(

<View style={{width: "100%", height: "100%",  backgroundColor: "#eeeeee",flexDirection:"column", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center"}}>

    <Text>Email</Text>
    <TextInput
    value={this.state.username}
    autoCorrect={false}
    onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
    style={{width: "80%", height: "10%", backgroundColor: "white", padding: "2%", margin:"2%"}}
    placeholder={"Enter Email"}
    autoComplete={"off"}
    />

    <Text>Password</Text>
    <TextInput
    value= {this.state.password}
    autoCorrect={false}
    onChange={this.onChangePassword}
    style={{width: "80%", height: "10%", backgroundColor: "white", padding: "2%", margin:"2%"}}
    placeholder={"Enter Password"}
    secureTextEntry={true} 
    />
    <Button title="Sign Up" style={{backgroundColor: "blue", padding: "2%", margin:"2%"}} onPress={(e)=>{this.createUser(e)}}></Button>
     <Text>{this.state.error}</Text>
    <View style={{width: "100%", height:"20%"}}></View>
    </View>



);

}
}


export default Auth;
```

I have tried replacing

```
state = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
    error: ""}
```

with

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state =  {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      error: ""};

    this.createUser = this.createUser.bind(this);

  }
```

I have also tried replacing:

```
<Button title="Sign Up" style={{backgroundColor: "blue", padding: "2%", margin:"2%"}} onPress={this.createUser}></Button>
```

and

```
 createUser = () =>{
```

with

```
<Button title="Sign Up" style={{backgroundColor: "blue", padding: "2%", margin:"2%"}} onPress={(e)=>{this.createUser(e)}}></Button>
```

and

```
createUser = (event) =>{
```

But neither of these have worked.

Comment: Would you like to share the error screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is following setState:
`{this.setState({error: 2})}`

This is because the line

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {
```

will change the this context due the use of `function()`

Change it to an **arrow function** to keep the this context.
-->

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password).catch((error) => {
```